# React component scrolls during update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a textbox that should be used to filter the content of a table. Every time the user types something, an action is dispatched that issues a request to the server for the desired data.

The thing is: every time the user types something, the page scrolls almost completely to the bottom. I think maybe due to the component's update.

To isolate the issue i removed everything from the page except for the editbox and the result is the same. This is the situation pre-input:

[image: The editbox is on top]

and this is what happens after the action is triggered by typing into the box:

[image: The page scrolls almost to the bottom]

I'm obviously doing something wrong, although I can't figure out what. This is my code (clutter removed for clarity):

```
  handleSearch(event) {
    const { dispatch, id } = this.props;

    dispatch(filterData(id, event.target.value));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <FormGroup>
          <InputGroup>
            <FormControl type="text" onChange={this.filterData}/>
          </InputGroup>
        </FormGroup>
      </form>
    );
  }
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: It could be anything in the `this.filterData` or anywhere else... you are not providing enough context to get help.

Comment: look at preventing default events in react

Comment: @GoshaArinich the filterData simply calls a server API with a fetch and stores the result, I didn't add it because it's not the API per se to cause this weird behaviour but the object update itself.

Answer (score 0):

After a few more hours of debugging I found the cause: during the search I show a "Loading..." writing to alert the user that a search is in progress. The loading part is much shorter than the table, so the page scrolls accordingly to offset for this change in height: from 800px to 100px. I didn't find a more elegant solution, so for the moment I'm constraining the loading screen to be the same height of the table.